# Is there any book that treat time-dependent perturbation theory with rigorous mathematics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, resource-recommendations, perturbation-theory

I am searching for rigorous mathematics  books or notes for time dependent perturbation theory.

For introductory quantum mechanics there is the excellent book  *spectral theory and quantum mechanics* by Valter Moretti and for time-independent perturbation theory there is the book *Perturbation theory for linear operators* from Kato which is a good book.

Is there any book that treat time dependent perturbation theory 
with rigorous mathematics?

Comment: I don't know if this book contains what you are looking for but might help you: _Advanced Mathematical Methods for Scientists and Engineers_ vol. 1 by Bender and Orszag. https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-3069-2. Lecture course by Prof. Bender https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LYNOGk3ZjFM&list=PLOFVFbzrQ49TNlDOxxCAjC7kbnorAR1MU.

Answer (score -1):

During my bachelor, I found quite useful the book *Quantum Mechanics Vol.2* by Cohen-Tannoudji, which treates the basics of time dependent perturbation theory really well in my opinion, and with some examples. However, there are other books more focused on a time dependent analysis of Quantum Mechanics like *Introduction to Quantum Mechanics: A time dependent perspective* by David J. Tannor, which is also quite good.

I hope you find these references useful!

Comment: tks for your answer but those books that you indicate me are not the level i am searching for.

Comment: Cohen-Tannoudji's book is a great introduction but definitely not on the rigorous maths side.