# Reference request: upper-level undergraduate treatment of time-dependent perturbation theory using the interaction picture approach

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, perturbation-theory

I find the treatment of time-dependent perturbation theory in Griffiths to be quite difficult/intensive. Our professor introduced us to the idea of using the interaction picture and this feels much easier to me so far. Are there any well-received undergraduate QM textbooks which take this approach? Problems/examples a must.

If anyone recognizes these lecture notes(?), they seem a good reference! (I only have a few page excerpt.)

[image]

Comment: Sakurai’s modern Quantum Mechanics has a good chapter on it.  You could also try https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/dbs26/PQM/chap9.pdf

Comment: @SuperfastJellyfish perfect! :D thank you so much, Skinner is great, these will be very useful!

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/525685/2451 and liks therein.